# What am i missing on my table creations / returns that they are nil?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm currently learning and trying to write a script for a map i created for a pretty old game (Settlers 5 Heritage of Kings) and while doing so i tried to split up my code in different files for organization purposes, since i dont want to put all my code in one single file. I learned so far, that the lua engine implemented in the game runs on 5.0.2. Now to adress my problem: i have a file called s5lualib in which i set up some basic values in a table like this:

```
S5LuaLib = {}

S5LuaLib.mission = _VERSION
S5LuaLib.diplomacy = "world"
S5LuaLib.map = Map

return S5LuaLib
```

which then gets called in my base.lua file like this:

```
function arbitrary()
    local s5lualib = S5LuaLib

    -- player one
    local playerIndex = s5lualib.map.createNewPlayer()
end
```

Additionally i have a map.lua file which contains this:

```
local Map = {}

--Map.environment = Environment

Map.testValue = "Hello World"
Map.players = {}

function Map.createNewPlayer()
    player = Player
    player.initialize(table.getn(Map.players)+1)
    table.insert(Map.players, player)
    return player.id
end

return Map
```

The problem i cant wrap my head around is, that whenever the script stats executing on `arbitrary()` it throws me an error that S5LuaLib.map is a nil value. i tried googling and when i make `Map = {}` global, it works until it steps into the `createNewPlayer()` function, telling me that `player` is a nil value (and here the funny part: no matter if i make it local or global). I would love to know why making `Map = {}`global fixes at least the first layer, why it cant be found when made local despite being returned and also why `player` is nil no matter if i make it local or not. For clarity reasons here my player.lua file:

```
local Player = {}

Player.id = 0
Player.color = 0

function Player.initialize(id)
    Player.id = id
    Player.color = id
end

return Player
```

The game has a lua debugger attached to it which lets me read variable contents, table contents etc on runtime, hence i know that when loading the `map.lua` file, Map gets no value assigned and in turn returns nil.  I doublechecked if all neccessary files are indeed loaded by the engine, doublechecked for typos etc. i'm legit out of ideas. I'm guessing i'm getting bullied by some scoping shenanigans i'm not used to (i'm coming from java, last time i worked with lua was like ~10 years-ish ago) or just plain overlooking, any hint, help and / or answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn than how `require()` works.
First Rule: Every Lua Script that returns something can be required
Second Rule: First require cache the Return and every following require gets the cached result (package.loaded)
So my suggestion for you is...

```
S5LuaLib = {}

S5LuaLib.mission = _VERSION
S5LuaLib.diplomacy = "world"
S5LuaLib.map = require("map")

return S5LuaLib
```

The Function should do

```
function arbitrary()
    local s5lualib = require("s5lualib")

    -- player one
    local playerIndex = s5lualib.map.createNewPlayer()
end
```

And try in `map.lua`

```
player = require("player")
```

And keep in Mind: The Cached Version is the Master
Changes to them will be persistent over the whole Runtime except the Cache will be deleted (set to nil).
Example

```
package.loaded.test = function(...) print("Hey!", ...) return(...) end

require("test")("World")
-- ^-> package.loaded.test("World")
-- Destroying and freeing unused Memory
package.loaded.test = nil
collectgarbage()
```

...dont load "test.lua" from File and call directly the cached Version.

Comment: First of all: thanks for the answer, i'll try to keep require in mind! Now to the sad stuff: i tried to require it, which results in everything being nil, which kinda makes sense if i understand require correctly, since it has no idea where to load the files from, right? Normally the script for a map is kept all in a single file and will be packed into the mapfile itself in the end, so it would make sense for the gameengine to not support multifile stuff there. the engine provides a ```Script.Load(<path>)``` function however, but just loading the script files isnt working (hence my question)

Comment: I can load scripts with ```Script.Load(<path>)``` and they indeed get loaded, but the issue with it is, that if the script contains a local table even wheen returning it, i either cant access it, o it wont get initialized and i dont really understand why

Answer (score 0):

After reaching out to the settlers modding community and getting some detailed information about the engine i found out that my issue is, that the lua runtime integrated in the engine does indeed NOT return local tables from files, hence the issue that everything defined local returns nil. Thanks for the effort nonetheless!